# Area of a figure

Tags: calculus

I need to find the area limited by four straight lines, given by the equations $x=y, x=2y, x+y=a,x+3y=a$. Now, i just changed to another coordinates u and v, such that $$u = x+3y, v=x+y$$, and the equations are now $u = a, v = a, 0.6u = v, 0.5u = v$. So the answer should be $$\int_{0}^{a} \int_{0.5v}^{0.6v}|J| du dv = |J|0.1\frac{a^2}{2}$$, and the Jacobian is $(1.5)(0.5)-(0.5)(0.5) = 0.5$. So my answer is $$a^2/40$$

I am not understand where is my error. Someone could help me? Apparently, the answer should be $7a²/120$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your change of variables doesn't correspond to a good "sweeping" of the area.

Here is a convenient sweeping that, honestly, I couldn't have found without a preliminary graphics:

[image]

*Fig. 1: Case $a=3$.*

In fact, the main information brought by such a picture is the **identification of opposite sides**, here

$x+y=a$ with opposite side $x+3y=a$, and $x=y$ with opposite side $x=2y$.

Now, after having identified the mutual points of intersection $(0,0)$ and $(0,3)$, one considers a subset of lines passing through these points:

- (blue) lines with equations $x+vy=a$ for $v=1$ giving $x+y=a$ to $v=3$ giving  $x+3y=a$.
- (red) lines with equations $x=uy$ for $u=1$ giving $x=y$ to $u=2$ giving  $x=2y$.

Let us summarize:

$$\begin{cases}x&=&uy&\ \ (1)\\x+vy&=&a &\ \ (2)\end{cases} \ \ \ \ \ \text{for} \ 1 \le u \le 2, \ 1 \le v \le 3$$

giving (by plugging (1) into (2))

$$uy+vy=a \ \ \text{implying} \ \ y=\frac{a}{u+v}$$

Therefore, the change of variables formulas are:

$$\begin{cases}x&=&\frac{au}{u+v}\\y&=&\frac{a}{u+v}\end{cases}$$

$$J=\begin{vmatrix}av/(u+v)^2&-a/(u+v)^2\\-au/(u+v)^2&-a/(u+v)^2\end{vmatrix}=-\frac{a^2}{(u+v)^4}(u+v)=-\frac{a^2}{(u+v)^3}$$

The area is:

$$A=\int_{v=1}^{v=3}\left(\int_{u=1}^{u=2}|J|du\right)dv=a^2\int_{v=1}^{v=3}(-\frac12) \left(\frac{1}{(2+v)^2}-\frac{1}{(1+v)^2}\right)dv=$$

$$(-\frac12)a^2\left[\left(\frac{-1}{(2+3)}-\frac{-1}{(2+1)}\right)-\left(\frac{-1}{(1+3)}-\frac{-1}{(1+1)}\right)\right]=$$

$$=(-\frac12)a^2\left[-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\right]=$$

$$=\frac{7}{120}a^2$$

as desired.

Remark: (see fig. 2 below) I have attempted to consider lines as yours (in blue, lines with equations $x+3y=u$, in red lines with equations $x+y=v$) but I don't see how constraints $0.5v<u<0.6v \ \ 0<v<a$ can give the quadrilateral represented on figure 1.

[image]

*Fig. 2.*

Comment: I just added at the bottom of my answer a second figure. Any comment ?

Answer (score 2):

The change of variable you have used does not transform it to a region whose area you can obtain using single integral. You will still need to split it into two integrals. Here is what I would suggest -

Given we have lines $x = y, x = 2y, $ we use change of variable $ \displaystyle u = \frac{x}{y}$ and so $1 \leq u \leq 2$.

We also take $v = y$

Then $x+y = a \implies uv+v = a \ $ i.e $ \ \displaystyle v = \frac{a}{u+1}$

$x+3y = a \implies uv + 3v = a \ $ i.e $ \ \displaystyle v = \frac{a}{u+3}$

$x = uv, y = v \implies |J| = v$

So the integral becomes,

$\displaystyle \int_1^2 \int_{a/(u+3)}^{a/(u+1)} v \ dv \ du = \frac {a^2}{2} \int_1^2 \bigg(\frac{1}{(u+1)^2} - \frac{1}{(u+3)^2}\bigg) \ du$

$ = \displaystyle \frac {a^2}{2} \bigg[-\frac{1}{u+1} + \frac{1}{u+3}\bigg]_1^2 = \frac {7a^2}{120}$

Comment: [+1] Your change of variables is interesting but I lack intuition about what has driven you to take it.

Comment: @JeanMarie now that you have brought my attention back to the question, I was just seeing updates to your answer :) It was not there when I answered. Very nice work with the diagrams and explanation.

Comment: @JeanMarie Coming back to what drove me to choose the change of variable I did. $x = y, x = 2y$ being two lines that bound the region, I get a straight bound of $u$ between lines $u = 1, u = 2$ parallel to v-axis. Now given $x+y = a$ and $x+3y = a$, choosing $v = y$ gives two curves that are bounds of $v$.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the algebra wrong.  Given that u= x+ 3y and v= x+ y, then u- v= 2y so y= u/2- v/2.  Then v= x+ y= x+ u/2- v/2 so x= 3v/2- u/2.

Yes, the lines x+ y= a and x+ 3y= a become v= a and u= a.
The line x= 2y becomes 3v/2- u/2= 2(u/2- v/2), 3v- u= 2u- 2v so 5v= 3u and the line x= y becomes 3v/2- u/2= u/2- v/2 so 2v= u.
The four lines, in the uv-coordinate system are u= a, v= a, 5v= 3u and u= 2v.  5v= 3u is the same as v= 0.6u and u= 2v is the same as v= 0.5u, NOT "u= 0.6v" and "u= 0.5v" as you have.